# How do I setup default files permission automount USB drive on 20.04?

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, automount

Whenever I plug USB drive in the system(w/ vfat or exfat fs), it automount the drive with my login uid/gid & permission 0777 for every files, even if I manually unmount and remount it with mount command and all the options to specify uid, gid, file & dir mask, it still comes up with 0777 for every files & dirs. It really pisses me off. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: The `vfat` and `exfat` file systems do not understand what unix permissions values mean, so it's "lost in translation" when the file system is mounted for use 

Comment: You can change this behaviour by changing the filesystem on your usb device to something like ext4. That will erase all the data on the device so back it up first. It will also make the device unreadable from Windows so it’s a case of what functionality do you want most.

Comment: What system version is this? On my version, a vfat USB drive is automounted with 0755 for directories, 0744 for regular files.

Comment: @matigo Yes, I understand that, however I tried to remount it manually with "mount ... -o umask=0133", the result was overridden by the system's automount to 0777 on everything.

Comment: @PonJar yes, any other FS would have solved the problem, Unfortunately I use that USB disk on Winblow machine as well.

Comment: @vanadium It's 20.04LTS, all I need is a way to set the default automount options, but seems like I can't find any.